# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce: querying with API

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api

I'm desperately struggling again with the Google documentation, grrr. Please point me somebody to the rigth direction: i want to query Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce through Analytics API.

The main question is: is it in general possible? If yes: What API is it and where is the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reporting API will let you get at Enhanced Ecommerce as well as the rest of GA. Here is [Google's Reporting API v4 documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics).

Here is the [Ecommerce Dimensions and Metrics list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce) for getting the right API names for EEc data.

As a side note, the Reporting API is what the [Google Sheets GA add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) uses as well, and for anyone coming along who's not familiar with using the API: the Sheets add-on is a great way to start and get familiar with the API's syntax.